# R ggplot2 show.legend = FALSE not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based on the `celsius` data and code below, the plot is fine, it's just that `show.legend = F` is not working.

Why is that so?

I know this question has been asked previously, but I wanted to know to have an answer/comment in context to my code.

df =

```
    structure(list(CITYNAME = c("a", "b", "c", 
    "d", "e", "f", "g", 
    "h", "i", "j", "k", 
    "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", 
    "r", "s", "t", "u", 
    "w", "x", "y", "z"), AvgTMin = c(20.28, 
20.38, 20.08, 20.35, 20.38, 20.76, 21, 21.21, 20.45, 20.21, 21.18, 
20.29, 20.61, 20.44, 20.95, 19.75, 20.58, 20.32, 21.05, 20.28, 
20.09, 20.15, 20.73, 20.12)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
# Plot in Fahrenheit
df %>% mutate(AvgTMin = AvgTMin * (1.8) + 32) %>% # Convert from C to F
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(CITYNAME,AvgTMin), y = AvgTMin, fill = CITYNAME)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(60,70.3)) +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
      geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%0.2f", AvgTMin)), vjust=-0.2, size = 4,
                show.legend = FALSE) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = "Avg. Min. Temperature \u00B0F") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
      ggtitle("1980-2021 Temperature Trend By City")
```

Comment: Your code and `show.legend=FALSE` work fine. Maybe you could clarify what you mean by "show.legend = FALSE not working"

Comment: @stefan, the legend still shows.

Comment: @stefan `theme(legend.position = 'none')` works but I just wanted to why `show.legend` wasn't working. But, if it's working for you then I guess it could be a glitch.

Comment: `show.legend=FALSE` is used to not display a specific geom as part of the legend key, i.e. in your case where you added it to `geom_text` it prevents that a small letter "a" is added to the legend key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show.legend` must be put inside `geom_bar()`

```
df %>% mutate(AvgTMin = AvgTMin * (1.8) + 32) %>% # Convert from C to F
       ggplot(aes(x = reorder(CITYNAME,AvgTMin), y = AvgTMin, fill = CITYNAME)) +
       geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = F) +
       coord_cartesian(ylim = c(60,70.3)) +
       theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14)) +
       geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%0.2f", AvgTMin)), vjust=-0.2, size = 4) +
       labs(x = NULL, y = "Avg. Min. Temperature \u00B0F") + 
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
       ggtitle("1980-2021 Temperature Trend By City")
```

Comment: Alternately, add `+ guides(fill = "none")`.